# Spring Batch - handle worker configuration error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have a Spring Batch application scheduled to run every 30 minutes, that creates workers on the Cloud as separate pods.

In the Configuration class, one of the beans connects to a database and reads some properties. If this DB connection fails for some reason, then the worker does not start and the Master job does not get triggered again after 30 minutes.

This is happening because if the worker fails on startup itself, it does not update the final status in the DB or communicate it to the master as Failed. Hence, the Master assumes it is still running and does not trigger the Batch again.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this and how to ensure the Master triggers the workers again on the scheduled duration?

Comment: `that creates workers on the Cloud as separate pods`: How are workers created? How is the lifecycle of workers managed? Can you share more details about your setup?

Comment: Workers are created using the Docker resource loader. Periodically, the master job runs a query which fetches the list of records to be processed. Once it has the list, based on the size of the list, it spawns one or more worker pods, and partitions the load between them. These worker pods then process the data, and go into Completed state.

Comment: The manager cannot know about the worker's status if the worker does not report it. The manager can however be configured with a [timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/MessageChannelPartitionHandler.html#setTimeout-long-) for that. So if you want the manager to fail before the next schedule runs, you need to set the timeout to a value lower than 30 minutes. That said, I would recommend to make each schedule have its own job, so that a failed job does not affect subsequent schedules.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a handy property that can be added to the application.properties to set the timeout (couldn't find any) or do we have to set it through code?

Comment: No, you can set the timeout on the `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` or through the builder `RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilder#timeout`.

Comment: I see that MessageChannelPartitionHandler is under the Spring integration package. Should we be using Cloudstream for this to work, or will it work in our case directly (we don't have any message broker like Kafka between the master and worker pods right now)?

Comment: OK, we were using DeployerPartitionHandler and were able to set the timeout on that. But now we have a different issue. If there is a timeout, and the next time the batch is triggered via the schedule - if it fails because the previous workers were still running, then even after they Complete, it never starts any new workers on the next scheduled triggers. Any idea if this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is about High avaliablity.

You could add redis in the front of db. If we cannot read the config from redis and then connect the db.

2ndly, add retry service like resilience4j into your bean to read your config for multiple times.

3rdly, for warning, you could add related warning service of your cloud to inform you which pod  failed to start. Then you are able to restart that pod manually or automatically.

Comment: OK, we can add the resilience to read multiple times and the Redis layer, but is there no way to do the rescheduling automatically so that the scheduler runs and triggers the batch again?

The problem is that in Production, the batches are scheduled to run in the night. And all kinds of maintenance activity also happen in the night. So if there were a maintenance activity going on and the Batch happens to get triggered at the exact same instant, it doesn't run the next day at all unless we manually restart it.

Comment: I am sorry. I had a nightmare Oct to implement a real-time message queue so that I even didn't have a time to check the message on stackoverflow. I think I get what you mean right now. You must need the  service registry and discovery. If the worker pod failed due to the maintenance or any other errors. We would get notified. If your quartz job is on a 30min schedule, the excusive schedule service would notify the worker to do the job after 30mins. If this 30 min delay would affect your system, you must save the error info to somewhere and then call it after the center restarts the worker.